# dotless css reference not working in release mode (with Combress)

Tags: dotless, combres

i'm using dotless css.
This is my code

```
.jqmWindowBig
{
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: -400px;
    margin-top: -250px;
    .jqmWindowCommon;
}

.jqmWindowCommon {
    background-color: #EEE;
    color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    padding: 12px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

When i'm on my own machine, in debug mode, all css files (also this main.less file) are referenced separately.

In that case, the `jqmWindowBig` class is the combination of `jqmWindowBig` and `jqmWindowCommon`, and all works fine.

Now on production, combress creates one big file of all of my CSS files, and then, the CSS contains literaly the code as i entered it in the .LESS file, so the `.jqmWindowCommon` section is not replaced by the `'jqmWindowCommon'` section so the `jqmWindowBig` is incomplete.

This is my combress config:

```
<resourceSets url="~/combres.axd"
                defaultDuration="30"
                defaultVersion="auto"
                defaultDebugEnabled="auto"
                defaultIgnorePipelineWhenDebug="true"
                localChangeMonitorInterval="30"
                remoteChangeMonitorInterval="60"
                >

    <resourceSet name="siteCss" type="css" >
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/start.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/Site.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/reset.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/screen.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/razortemplates.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/logonsmall.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
      <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/MainLess.LESS" />
    </resourceSet>
```

So in short: the reference `.jqmWindowCommon;` is not replaced, when running in release mode.

EDIT
it's not only this which is not working, i can see that these kind of rules

```
width: @planningEventItemWidth;
```

are not working either, so basicly no .LESS functionality is working when combined with Combress>

Comment: Are you using @import "stylesheetname.css"; in the .less file?

Comment: Nope, no import in the .less file

Answer (score 1):

Your combres config is missing a filter for LESS:

```
<filters> 
  <filter type="Combres.Filters.DotLessCssFilter, Combres" />
</filters>
```

Comment: I gave you the bounty points for the answer, i'll check tomorrow wether it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you bring up your linked resource directly, you'll notice it probably has an error.  I don't think you can add css and less files in the same resourceSet.

**Updated**
**Confirmed that filters are per ResourceSet:**
https://github.com/buunguyen/combres/issues/5#issuecomment-12915712

You can get it to work by using the dotless filter and moving your less files to a separate resourceSet like this:

```
<filters>
  <filter type="Combres.Filters.DotLessCssCombineFilter, Combres" 
    acceptedResourceSets="siteLess"/>
</filters>
<resourceSet name="siteLess" type="css">
  <resource path="~/Content/StyleSheet/MainLess.LESS" />
</resourceSet>
```

Hope that helps.